# List Style Images in IE9

Tags: image, list, styles, internet-explorer-9, inverse

IE9 shows list style images inverted.
For example I'm using a tick as list-style-image, but IE9 showing them inverted.
How do I fix it?

p.s: I hate IE9 ! :|

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps explicitly  set the UL + LI to have text-direction:ltr?